# Quotation in string format

Tags: c#, escaping, string-formatting, epplus, double-quotes

I need help with a bit of string formatting and escaping. 
Starting from this string format:

> string.Format("=IF(OR({0}="";{1]="");"";{0}-{1})", cell1, cell2)

I'm trying to obtain this string:

> =IF(OR(L2="";M2="");"";L2-M2)

This is a string that I need to insert as an excel formula. I have tried with `string.Format`, I have tried with `@"..."`, I even tried concatenating string pieces and escaping the quotes.
No matter what I try, I always get this string:

> =IF(OR(L2=\"\";M2=\"\");\"\";L2-M2)

This breaks my excel file when I try to open it. I do not understand why the \ stay there.

Any tips would be welcomed. Thanks.

```
  int atCol = ws.Dimension.End.Column + 1;

  //insert the header
  ws.Cells[1, atCol].Value = "Diff. Quote letzte 2 Jahre";
  ws.Cells[1, atCol].Style.WrapText = true;

  for (int i = 2; i<=ws.Dimension.End.Row; i++)
  {
    var cell1 = ws.Cells[i, atCol + 1].Address;
    var cell2 = ws.Cells[i, atCol + 2].Address;
    //ws.Cells[i, atCol].Formula = string.Format("=IF(OR({0}=\"{2}\";{1}=\"{2}\");\"{2}\";{0}-{1})", cell1, cell2, string.Empty);
    //ws.Cells[i, atCol].Formula = string.Format(@"=IF(OR({0}="";{1}="");"";{0}-{1})", cell1, cell2);
    //string formula = string.Format(@"=IF(OR({0}="""";{1}="""");"""";{0}-{1})", cell1, cell2);
    //string formula = @"=IF(OR(" + cell1 + "=\"\";" + cell2 + "=\"\");\"\";" + cell1 + "-" + cell2 + ")";
    string formula = string.Format("=IF(OR({0}='';{1}='');'';{0}-{1})", cell1, cell2);
    ws.Cells[i, atCol].Formula = formula;
  }
```

I'm using Win10, VS2015, .Net 4.0 and EPPLUS framework for excel manipulation.

Comment: Why not give single quotes a go? `L2=''`

Comment: could you please give an example of the code snippets, especially the things you tried to escape along with the results that they produced?

Comment: I tried single quotes. The result is: =IF(OR(L2=\'\';M2=\'\');\'\';L2-M2)

Comment: Yeah the idea was not escaping them

Comment: looks fine for me `string inputStr = @"=IF(OR(L2="";M2="");"";L2-M2)";`

Comment: If you ask me, you should define your string in your program exactly the way wich your second quote states: `var formula = "=IF(OR(L2=\"\";M2=\"\");\"\";L2-M2)";
`

Comment: @un-lucky this is not valid C# code

Comment: @nozzleman: let me know why? can you please check [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L7qdaM)

Comment: @VictorB none of the commented out solutions worked?

Comment: None so far, unfortunately.

Comment: Try setting the cell Value property, then setting the formula to that. So `cell.Value = formula; cell.Formula = cell.Value;`.

Comment: This does not do anything either.

Comment: Weird behavior. I quick watch the string. The value column displays the string containing \. If I press the "Text Visualizer" button, the string is displayed without \. What gives?

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra information. When using the straightforward Interop assemblies from Microsoft both string escaping and value/formula setting works fine. This seems like something to do with EPPLUS. Unfortunately I don't have a project set up for that right now.

Comment: I do not think it has anything to do with the tools I'm using. Please read the previous comment. There is something weird about how string.Format works. Why does it return a string containing \? Printing that string with Console.Writeline or watching it with Text Visualizer removes the \

Comment: It's not weird, that's how strings store that data. I'm sure someone with a better understanding of the framework can explain why. It's not unique to string.Format either, it happens if you build it with stringbuilder or any other method. Happens whether you escape the value with `\"`, make it literal with `@""""` or use the unicode value `"\u0022\u0022"`. What I'm getting at is that everything else including Interop processes the escapes correctly, same as WriteLine like you said. My point is that EPPLUS seems to be doing a bad job of recognising escape sequences but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add one more (") before the others.

```
=IF(OR(L2="""";M2="""");"""";L2-M2)
```

Comment: this is how to escape double quotes from withing excel istself which is not what the OP asked for

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the string {1]= should be {1}=.  The following shows 2 ways you can escape double quotes.

```
string.Format("=IF(OR({0}=\"\";{1}=\"\");\"\"({0}-{1})", cell1, cell2);
string.Format(@"=IF(OR({0}="""";{1}="""");""""({0}-{1})", cell1, cell2);
```